# Ubuntu desktop CD ISO boot problems

Tags: installation

I am attempting to boot from an ISO file burned to CD (yes, did the burn right with an ISO burner application) and can't get anywhere.  The ISO file is the 32bit 12.x available on the ubuntu website.  This is the second ISO file, the first was used on a USB with identical results.

I have successfully swapped to CD boot using f12.  I can access the ubuntu boot menus by hitting any key....  it seems any choices options all result in the same problem:

It displays the ubuntu logo with the white/red dots underneath.  Dots color cycle about 3-5 times and then it hangs and goes no further.  No error message is displayed. Computer is a Dell Inspiron N7010 that had a big windows 7 blowup and without the original disk, I'm stuck.  There is a generic windows install, but without driver support I'm not going far (no ethernet, etc)

I did run the "check the disk" option and it examined the CD and said everything is fine.

N

Comment: Can you try the steps as mentioned here [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075)

Answer (score 0):

Is the hard drive working on the laptop? Have you gone into setup on the BIOS and verified that your hard drive is present and visible? Have you tried the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option? That should read the OS into memory and can help diagnose hardware issues. If you have no bootable partitions or if the drive just failed, then it would be hard to perform an install and it would just appear to hang.

One thing have also seen in the boot up sequence for the install is a long "hang" if too many peripherals are installed (external storage usually the culprit). Can you verify that no external drives are attached as well? That might take a while to start the install as it verifies the external drives as well.

Just my personal experience though YMMV. Would not expect a failure to install these days unless you require the alternative Boot ISO due to some driver issues.

Comment: I have tried the "without installing" option, same result. It sees the drive, and will boot into my garbage windows install if I let it.  There are no peripherals.  All the various different attempts result in the same crash/hang- midway through a boot up.

Comment: Would suggest trying this link to the Precise download: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ , then select the Alternate install CD. Could be a driver issue that only gets fixed when the driver is loaded.